# WxPython limit user from moving away from a specified directory

Tags: python, user-interface, directory, wxpython

After creating a `wx.DirDialog` at a certain path (ex. "C:\Users\ExampleUser\Documents"), is there a way to limit the user from moving away from the specified folder?

Comment: Why not just populate a list with the contents of said directory and call it a day?

Comment: The user will be picking the file name of a photo, but I can't have them picking pictures from another directory. A list wouldn't suffice for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The user will be picking the file name of a photo

So you don't want `DirDialog` but `FileDialog`
I don't think that is a way of restricting the widget to a specific directory but you could certainly do it within your code. e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import wx
import os

class choose(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        dirname = os.getcwd()
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose Image file", dirname, "", "Image files (jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*", style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
        my_file = "No file selected"
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            pass
        else:
            sel_dir = dlg.GetDirectory()
            if sel_dir != dirname:
                wx.MessageBox('Please choose a file from the given directory', 'Error', wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
            else:
                my_file = dlg.GetFilename()
        print "Chosen file:",my_file
        self.Destroy()

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_app = wx.App()
    p = choose(None)
    my_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I am sad that there isn't a way of limiting the user implicitly, but this is the next best thing. Thanks!